# Delay script until all messages have been passed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, message

As usual, I have Googled this a fair bit and read up on the Message Passing API, but, again, I've had to resort to the good fellas at StackOverflow.

My question is this: When passing messages between a Google Chrome extension's background page and content script, is there any way to make it asynchronous - that is, to delay the JavaScript until the messages are detected as being successfully being passed?

I have a function immediately after the message-passing function makes use of the `localStorage` data that is passed. On first runs the script always results in an error, due to the data not being passed fast enough.

Currently, I'm circumventing this with `setTimeout(nextFunction, 250);` but that's hardly an elegant or practical solution, as the amount and size of the values passed is always going to change and I have no way of knowing how long it needs to pass the values. Plus, I would imagine, that passing times are relative to the browser version and the user's system.

In short, I *need* it to be dynamic.

I have considered something like

```
function passMessages(){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "methodName"}, function(response) {
        localStorage["lsName"] = response.data;
    });

    checkPassedMessages();
}

function checkPassedMessages(){
    if (!localStorage["lsName"]){
        setTimeout(checkPassedMessages, 100); //Recheck until data exists
    } else {
         continueOn();
    }
}
```

but I need to pass quite a lot of data (at least 20 values) and, frankly, it's not practical to `!localStorage["lsName1"] && !localStorage["lsName2"]` etc etc. Plus I don't even know if that would work or not.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

**Update:** Still no answer, unfortunately. Can anyone offer any help at all? :/

Comment: What type of extension are you trying to create? Is it a browser action? By saying `Google Chrome extension's background page` do you mean the html background page that you include in the `background.page` section of the `manifest.json` file? Are you trying to send data from the background page to the content script or the other way round?

Comment: I'm trying to send data from the background page to the content script.

Comment: Also, yes the background page is a HTML file included in the manifest.json file.

Comment: Could you please provide the `manifest.json` file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether I'm interpreting your question wrong. As far as I understand you are sending request from your extension page to a content script. The request handler in the content handler does some operation on the message passed after which you need the control back in the extension page. If this is what you need you have everything in the [Google Extension Documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). The following code works

```
//Passing the message
function passMessages(){
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "methodName"}, function(response) {
    //callback function that will be called from the receiving end

    continueOn();
  });
}

//Recieving the message
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     //Do the required operation with the message passed and call sendResponse

     sendResponse();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are interpreting it wrong. My message passing system works perfectly. I was just asking if there was some kind of method or additional argument that you can attach to the message passing functions to make them synchronous - to make them wait until the process (of passing messages) is complete before proceeding.

Comment: The only difference between the code that you have posted and the one that I have posted is that I'm calling `continueOn` within the request callback. You send some message. After the receiver is done with the message it calls back the request callback set while sending the request. So the message has been passed and the program control comes back to the sender only after the message has been dealt with. This is pretty much what synchronous calls do right.

Comment: But I have, like, 20 messages to pass. I can't link a function to every single message pass.. That's even less practical that what I planned to do..

Comment: Instead of passing 20 messages separately, can't you pass an array with all the 20 messages and get it over with in one shot?

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that `localStorage` doesn't support anything but strings. And there's a few other complications too (data types, variable names, etc).

Comment: You can store all your data as a JSON object. Then to store into the localStorage as `localStorage["data"] = JSON.stringify(jsonObject)`. This converts your data in jsonObject to a string and stores it in the localStorage. When you want to retrieve the data, retrieve it as `var jsonObject = JSON.parse(localStorage["data"])`. You'll get back your data as a JSON object. So pass all your data at once in as  JSON object. Store it as a string and retireve it back as JSON wherever you want to.

Comment: But this still comes back to delaying the script until all data has been passed..

Comment: I ended up doing it similar to your suggested method, so I'll give you the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the general (ie, on any platform where you are communicating between distinct threads of execution) case of this problem by collecting the information passed, while waiting for some sort of following "go" message before you begin processing the collected information.  You can use the same idea to have the sender wait for the complete reply.

Of course it's possible that your particular platform provides tools for doing this; but if not, you can always build the general solution by hand.

Comment: But I still need to know how to go abouts doing this?

Comment: Program logic. - Something like while(not_go_message(recvd)) buffer += recvd; process(buffer); in whatever language you are solving your particular version of the problem in.

Comment: It does, you just have to write it in the context of your environment, for example depending on how you get data  you might have to do it as a state machine.

Comment: But I don't know how to do that. As I said to the other guy, I was just hoping for some kind of method that I could attach to something to make it wait. :/

Comment: Wow. What a shocking answer. Why'd you think I'm here?